# How can I find the value of s1 and s2 such that from 1:5000 & 5001:10000 the values should be different?

Tags: matlab, simulation

This is my code:

```
  % Initial values
  x0 = 0.5;
  y0 = 0.6;
  dt = 0.01;
  time = 100; % time
  num_iteration = ceil(time / dt);
  num_trajectory = 10000; % Number of trajectories
  c = 1; % constant
  y = zeros(num_trajectory, num_iteration) + y0;
  x = zeros(num_trajectory, num_iteration) + x0;
  s1 = zeros(1, num_trajectory);
  s2 = zeros(num_trajectory);
  for t = 1:5000 % iteration 
     s1 = 2*x(:, t).^2./(y(:, t) + x(:, t) + c);
     s2 = 2*y(:, t);
  end
  for t1 = 5000:10000 % iteration
     s1 = x(:, t1)./y(:, t1);
     s2 = y(:, t1); 
  end
```

I was unable to find `s1` and `s2` such that: for `1:5000`, `s1` and `s2` will have a value say, `(0.7, 0.4)` respectively, and from `5001:10000` `s1` and `s2` will also have a different value. Overall the vectors `s1` and `s2` should show some changes as the time `t` changes.

How can I find such values?

Comment: your x and y arrays are 10000x10000 and your s1 and s2 are 10000x1. If you look at your code every time you loop through the 1:5000 you are overwriting the 10000x1 column. So the final result you get is actually just the result from the 10000th t1 loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment